# Using websockets with Alt

Tags: websocket, reactjs, flux, alt

Where do websockets fit into the [Alt](http://alt.js.org/) way of doing flux? What should be responsible for translating socket messages into actions and vice versa?

- Components
- Stores
- Containers
- Actions
- Sources

EDIT:

Here's what I have now which seems to work, but please post an answer if you have a flux-appropriate way of doing things.

```
var alt = require('../alt');
var UserActions = require('../actions/UserActions');

var socket = io();
socket.on("user", function(user) {
  UserActions.addUser(user);
});

class UserStore {
  constructor() {
    this.users = [{id:1, name: "michael"}, { id:2, name: "lauren"}];

    this.bindListeners({
      handleUpdateUsers: UserActions.UPDATE_USERS,
      handleAddUser: UserActions.ADD_USER
    });


  }

  handleUpdateUsers(users) {
    this.users = users;
  }

  handleAddUser(user) {
    this.users.push(user);
  }
}

module.exports = alt.createStore(UserStore, 'UserStore');
```

Comment: I'm doing somthing with socket.io and redux. My client emits are normal events like form submit etc that don't interact with the store.. then my client listens (`on('server:newPlayer')`, for instance) is registered in my component constructor.. the callback dispatches an action creator

Comment: The client listen doesn't make sense to put in the component though, does it? Since multiple components might rely on the same store (say, an array of Users) wouldn't it make sense to package the socket listeners in a source or store somehow?

Comment: My client listen callbacks are inside my root component's constructor. It does make sense because I need access to redux's `dispatch` which gets passed through props.

Comment: Also, I think that's the least important part of the setup. As long as your socket listeners can dispatch actions, it doesn't matter where you register them. I'm binding / unbinding them in certain child components. For instance, I don't want a socket event handler enabled if I know the component that needs it won't be rendered.

Comment: That's a good point @azium. It could almost be in some arbitary socketsetup.js file... I'll put in the Q what I have now which seems to be working.